# Unable to connect Arduino to NVIDIA Jetson TK1 dev board

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arduino, nvidia

I have been trying to pass serial communications between the Jetson and an Arduino Nano, and have discovered that the Jetson will not provide the Arduino with a serial port (should be something like ttyACM0). lsusb in the terminal doesn't identify an Arduino, instead, it lists a generic "Future Technology Devices International" USB serial device. My assumption is that there is a driver issue, but I can find no helpful information for installing or even finding any drivers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you connecting the 2 boards?

Comment: Oh, I guess you are connecting them via USB. What OS does the Jetson run? If you plug in the Arduino, and then use the dmesg command, do you see any messages relating to USB?

Comment: OK, I checked, you are running a modded Ubuntu 14.04 OS. There are reported problems with the Serial drivers for this version. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2208751

Comment: @Greycon Hi, thanks for your reply(s)! It seems you might be right about it being buggy. That being said, I have been sent a YouTube video of someone successfully connecting an Arduino seemingly right out of the box. It looks like I may end up trying to reinstall L4T (the modded Ubuntu 14.04) and hope that the problem doesn't come from one of the programs I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this to work, using [this tutorial](http://elinux.org/Jetson/Tutorials/Connect_To_Arduino). I had tried it before, couldn't get past the **Configuring the kernel** section. Having tried it again in desperation yesterday, it worked fine. I must not have been paying attention!

Answer (score 0):

Just install the current version of the "grinch" kernel, this custom kernel
has the drivers included.

find more info on the Nvidia dev forum:
[grinch kernel](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/766303/embedded-systems/-customkernel-the-grinch-19-3-6-for-jetson-tk1/)